# React-Native ListView under NavigatorIOS

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/react-native-introduction/) to use TabBarIOS and NavigatorIOS but my problem is that the ListView passes "under" the Navigator bar like in the screenshot above

[image: img]

Here is my code :

```
var React = require('react-native');

var REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction';

var {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Component,
    ListView,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
   } = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 10,
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  author: {
    color: '#656565',
  },
 separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#dddddd',
  },
  listView: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  loading: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

class BookList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchData();
 }

    fetchData() {
      fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.items),
            isLoading: false,
          });
        })
        .done();
    }

render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return this.renderLoadingView();
  }

  return (
  <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
      style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
}

renderLoadingView() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
       <ActivityIndicatorIOS
          size='large'/>
                  <Text>
            Loading books...
                  </Text>
          </View>
  );
}

renderBook(book) {
  return (
       <TouchableHighlight>
         <View>
             <View style={styles.container}>
                     <Image
                         source={{ uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail }}
                         style={styles.thumbnail} />
                     <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                     <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                     </View>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.separator} />
     </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>
  );
     }
    }

module.exports = BookList;
```

I found happened when I call this block of code (when it's loading)

```
renderLoadingView() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
                      <ActivityIndicatorIOS
              size='large'/>
                      <Text>
                Loading books...
                      </Text>
              </View>
  );
}
```

What's wrong? In the tutorial it works great but not in mine..

Answer (score 2):

When using the NavigatorIOS you need to add a marginTop to the next component of whatever the height is, so try something like marginTop:60 in the first component you are rendering.

Comment: It does the trick, thanks. But I think there is a "real" answer about this because when I don't call the renderLoadingView() method it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';